# Check valid domains in an eMail address

Tags: php

I have the following function that checks whether an eMail is valid:

```
function validate_email ($getemail, $type)
{
    $email = $getemail;
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $chkdomain = explode("@", $email);
        $domain = $chkdomain[1];
        switch ($type) :
            case 1: //FOR USERS
                if ($domain == "oxfordmontessori.com" || $domain == "student.com" || $domain == "vendor.com")
                    return 'Not Valid';
                else
                    return TRUE;
        endswitch
        ;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I am calling function in this way.

```
var_dump($email);
$response = validate_email($email, '1');
var_dump($response);
if ($response == FALSE) {
    $error = "Incorrect Email-Id";
} elseif ($response == 'Not Valid') {
    $error = "Email domain is not valid for user.";
}
var_dump($response);
```

The code has the following issues

1. Function is that not much restrict with email validation like `sunrise@o.com` and 'sunrise@o.c' both are consider as valid email id's.
2. If function return TRUE than also I get "Email domain is not valid for user."

One issue is still their that is on return of TRUE it gives me error `Email domain is not valid for user.`

Comment: Thanks for editing. Can you please try to clarify the issues you have with the validation function. Your current wording makes it hard to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

its not working because if the domain is set to `oxfordmontessori.com` `student.com` or `vendor.com`, it returns "Not Valid", so `@a.com` and `@b.com` will return true. Unless your system is designed to stop people from using those specific domains.

You should probably have either an external variable to store the error, or a pointer in the arguments, rather than returning multiple data types from the function. Either a true or false, maybe an integer, but not a mix of true, false, and string. I think strings (when checked against boolean operators) return true every time.

Comment: Issue is same if I return 'Not Valid' it gives me error for email doesn't available for use but in case if I get true as return than also it gives me same error.

Comment: @Rahul because strings when checked against a true boolean operation return true. don't mix data types, use an int, or an error registry (so if false is returned, check the registry)

Answer (score -4):

you can also use  [html5 email inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp) for validation. 
Validation is mostly done by regex functions like

```
preg_match()
```

[Here is an example of using regular expressions for validating email addresses](http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/validate-an-email-address-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: the code in the suggested example uses the deprecated eregi* family of functions and wont allow for TLD's like .museum or .info. HTML5 validation is client side and easily bypassed so its not helpful.

Comment: It also doesn't handle excapable characters in mailbox names. And there are lots of other things which valid as an "email address" it doesn't address either (really its only trying to validate an ADDR_spec - and not doing that very well).

Comment: ereg is deprecated preg is not. regex can do all OP requested

Comment: Never trust validation on the client side.  It's only meant as to improve workflow, but you **must** also validate the data on the server room.